# Stop WordPress redirecting comment-page-1 to the post page?

Tags: comments

I would like to have a separate page for the comments on a post, such that this page: `/2011/02/post-name/` just shows the post and then you click a link to view the comments, taking you to a page like this: `/2011/02/post-name/comment-page-1/`

I will then check the URL to see if "comment-page-x" is in it, and display the page differently if so (remove the post, so people don't have to scroll past that every time, and also style things a bit differently).

This would work, but WordPress redirects `comment-page-1` to the post page - I need it to keep `comment-page-1` there in the URL.

Is this possible? How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: upvotet the Q. As Mike said: good one :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question! WordPress assigns your comment page number to the query var `'cpage'` which gets set when your URL has `/comment-page-1/` at the end. So your culprit is in the `redirect_canonical()` function, line 192 of `/wp-includes/canoncial.php`.

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') || is_feed() || get_query_var('cpage') ) {
```

Since the `redirect_canonical()` function gets set as an action what we can do is to insert our own function to be called instead, have our function set the `'cpage'` query var to `false`, call `redirect_canonical()`, and then set `'cpage'` back to what it was; that will keep WordPress from redirecting on you.

To insert your own function you need to call the two hook `'init'` and `'template_redirect'` like so being sure to set the `'init'` hook to be called after the `do_action()` inside WordPress core that adds `redirect_canonical()`:

```
add_action('init','yoursite_init',11); //11=lower priority
function yoursite_init() {
  remove_action('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
  add_action('template_redirect','yoursite_redirect_canonical');
}

add_action('template_redirect','yoursite_redirect_canonical');
function yoursite_redirect_canonical($requested_url=null, $do_redirect=true) {
  $cpage = get_query_var('cpage');
  set_query_var('cpage',false);
  redirect_canonical($requested_url, $do_redirect);
  set_query_var('cpage',$cpage);
}
```

Then of course you need to do something with your `'cpage'`.  You can either check for the value returned by `get_query_var('cpage')` or you can add another hook to allow you to create a comment-specific template which is what I did. It will add look for a theme template file with the same as it would normally load but with `[comments].php` at the end of the name instead of `.php`, i.e. `single[comments].php`. *Note* that I set priority for this filter to be 11; you may need to set to an even larger number if a plugin you use adds itself after your hook:

```
add_filter('single_template','yoursite_single_template',11);
function yoursite_single_template($template) {
  if (get_query_var('cpage'))
    $template = str_replace('.php','[comments].php',$template);
  return $template;
}
```

And here's the proof that it all works!

[image: Screenshot of Custom WordPress Page Template for Comments]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/My_Test_%7C_WordPress_3.0_Test_Site-20110211-084920.png))</sub>

Comment: Short.... wow! Too bad we can't do a +10 over here...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but a question - where can I put this code? I've tried in functions.php but not having much luck. Assuming I'm using twentyten theme, where in the file do I add the code?

Comment: @Shaun - Figures. :) The one time I didn't add the following text to my answer I get called for it: *"You can add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file or in a `.php` file of a plugin you might be writing."*  But you say that is not working? What exactly is it not doing? Have you put `echo "Test"; exit;` statements in each of the functions to make sure the hooks are firing? Do you have plugins that may be conflicting? Did you try changing `11` in two places to `100?` Did you include all the code? Did you create a theme template file called `single[comments].php`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Brilliant, thanks. I did not create the single[comments].php!

Comment: @Shaun - Glad I could help!